# Is the statement, 'For each set $A$, $A⊆ P(A)$', true or false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I thought that the statement,
 $A ⊆ P(A)$
is true because the power set of A contains all the elements of $A$, but according to the solutions this statement should be false. I cannot seem to find the reasons for that...

What is the right answer?

Comment: There are two kinds of "contain" possible: $\in$ and $\subseteq$. Be sure to distinguish them

Comment: $A \in P(A)$ but $A \nsubseteq P(A) $

Comment: Technically, sets $A$ with the property that $A \subseteq P(A)$ are called [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set). To see that not every set is transitive, see Asaf Karagila's answer.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Let $A=\{a\}$, where $a$ is anything but the empty set.

Comment: I might add that for general such $a$ you need the axiom of foundation to rule out $a = \{a\}$ (although it is easy to find a specific $a$ for which your example can be shown to work without using foundation.)

Comment: As always, thank you for the additional commentary!

Comment: And thank you for tolerating it :-)

Answer (score 1):

The power set of A does not necessarily contain all the members of A unless very special conditions are met. It does have A *as a member*. Another way to understand the power set of A is as the set whose *members* contain only members of A, and which has every such set among its members. It will only contain every member of A if every member of A is also a subset of A--that is, if it's a transitive set.